# Ubuntu-SDK Installation On Saucy Salamander 13.10 does not show ubuntu project templates

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I've installed the ubuntu-sdk using the instructions [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/get-started/), wherein I was instructed to execute

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

The installation succeeded, at least in some ways. However, I see that in the tutorials there is a project wizard which includes a set of project types for ubuntu projects. Upon starting the Ubuntu-SDK from dash, and attempting to start a new project using CTRL+N, I see the following :

[image: My Ubuntu New Project Dialog Window]

It can be plainly seen that there is no "Ubuntu" project template category. How can I resolve this problem ?

I've launched qtcreator with

```
qtcreator -customwizard-verbose
```

full text here http://pastebin.com/VCbpunAY

I see that there are missing wizard.xml files referenced in that file. Is it possible that these are the cause of the problem?

I'm running :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

Comment: Did you restart the system?

Comment: Is that a requirement of the installation, or a shot in the dark ? Linux rarely requires restarts for something like this

Comment: I have now rebooted, without effect. My objection to this particular piece of advice is that it is a shotgun strategy which is often provided without really considering the potential causes of a symptom, nor the potential benefits of rebooting. Nevertheless, I appreciate you weighing in Braiam. We can now rule out "hot install" related issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there are some packages you didn´t install:

```
sudo apt-get -f update
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

I'm personally interested in start using the SDK.

Comment: done, without effect. Thanks for the advice though. Any other thoughts ?